# Background on Sections of Grouped UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

How to set a background image or view to a section of a grouped UITableView? I know how to set the background of the cells and how to set a fixed background for the table view, but what i need is a background for a section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your only option here is to cut your background up into the shape of the individual cells and set it as the cell backgrounds. There no method that allows you to return a view for the background of an entire section.